# Efficient way to create complex JavaScript shapes

Tags: javascript, shapes, coding-efficiency

I have been trying to create complex JavaScript shapes (to the end effect of functioning gauges). However, this is a very slow process when creating each individual part programmatically.

I was hoping to find some way to do this more effectively than this. Adobe Animate looked hopeful, but it is very overkill for what I need. I was hoping that there was some software or method to creative JavaScript shapes more effectively than writing each piece of code.

Thank you for any advice you may have.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you mean Canvas since you said JavaScript shapes. I've used htmlcanvas studio for another project and it seemed ok. Have a look here http://www.htmlcanvasstudio.com/

Once your shape is created. Include it into a function so this way you can new the same shape over and over again. It may also be an object of course. Then you can create instances of it with Object.create(square) for example.

```js
function someShape () {
  // paste generated code
  console.log('your shape has been created');
}


const shape = new someShape();

// or
new someShape();
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast response! This was more or less what I was looking for. I will check it out soon, and hopefully it will do everything that is needed :) Thank you again.

Comment: You are welcome! Let me know if it works out for you. If it helps, please bump up my answer :D. Looking to unlock some awesome badges :D

Comment: I will do my best ;) (I haven't been active enough to have it publicly shown though, but it should count towards them badges ;) )

Comment: I checked it out and it's not bad, doesn't quite have the level of detail I am needing though :/ Thank you again for your help however!